# Laravel 5 how to check User exists in my other table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to check if user exists in my table or redirect back with a message using Laravel 5.6?

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $isEmailExists = Niigem::where('email', $data['email'])->count();
    if($isEmailExists){
        User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
    }
}
```

I Added my Create method here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Niigem;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data){

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|exists:niigems',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

}

Comment: You want to create a new `user` if they exist in the `nigem` table?

Comment: Also, show us where you are trying to call this `create` method.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya, in RegisterController

Comment: What's the condition... If the exist or if they don't exist? and what's the name of the table you are checking against?

Comment: `Niigem` table when registering user's mail exists in `Niigem table`, Now can be registered If don't exists return message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users|exists:niigems',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    User::create([
    'name'     => $data['name'],
    'email'    => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return something when the user is created.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $isEmailExists = Niigem::where('email', $data['email'])->count();
    if($isEmailExists){
        User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        return ........ you need to return something here
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35` Same error. I even don't understand the error

Comment: what did you return? the user?

Comment: Thank you sir i found the solution that i was seeking. `'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users|exists:niigems',` this line works well i guess. t

Answer (score 2):

I see your are trying to create a new user if they exist in the `niigem` table. To do it the Laravel way, you have to validate using Laravel's `validation` class. So,  this should work:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|exists:niigem',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35`

Comment: show us the place you are trying to use this `create` method

Comment: Let me update my Question, And I'm using in my RegisterController

Comment: Please do. That would help. Also let us know which controller this method is in.

Comment: `'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users|exists:niigems',`  that line helped me a lot. Thank you sir. I think we found solution

Comment: Seen. What you have in your `routes` file?

Comment: Good. Glad I could help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
Niigem::firstOrCreate(['email' => 'dummy@domain.com'], ['name'=> $data['name'], 'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query you can use both condition as per your need:

$user = Niigem::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();

if ($user === null) {

// user doesn't exist

}

if ($user !== null)

{

// user doesn't exist

}